# Trying to read a SOAP API using ASP.NET core Razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-core, soap

I am trying to simply consume a really simple SOAP API using .net core in a razor page (however, I don't care if razor or not). The API provides IP Geo location info based on the IP address. 
WSDL for the tool is http://ws.cdyne.com/ip2geo/ip2geo.asmx?WSDL

ResolveIP, basically takes 2 parameters

ipAddress string

licenseKey string - This is just 0 for testing

So, after adding connected service to VS2017, (I called it GeoIPService) this is the code I am trying to get working. Should be simple, but I am having a bit of trouble with it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is my razor page. I haven't done much with SOAP or API's so trying to get started.

...

```
@{

    var IpService = new GeoIPService.P2GeoSoapClient;
    var IpResult = IpService.ResolveIPAsync("203.18.58.20", "0");
    @IpResult;
}
```

I think it's more a syntax issue. VS is saying P2GeoSoapClient doesn't have a constructor that takes 0 arguments. I think I need to put something after p2GeoSoapClient, eg P2GeoSoapClient(argument); but I can figure out what.

Comment: If you have created that P2GeoSoapClient then it should have a ctor that tales 0 arguments. Are you sure you are not simply missing `()` at the end of: `var IpService = new GeoIPService.P2GeoSoapClient;`? If you got that class from somewhere check the implementation as cdyne' own wiki: https://wiki.cdyne.com/index.php/IP2Geo  uses a parameterless constructor as well.

Comment: Thanks Rene, I tried with with just a () at the end with no luck. However, thanks for finding cdyne's wiki, I didn't know it was there. I will check that out, sure it's a simple thing I'm missing. Thanks again mate. Appreciate you pointing me in the right direction.